# TypeError: this.props.likeMovie is not a function

Tags: reactjs, firebase

i am using ReactJs and firebase.
I have this error when i try to push "like data" to the db.

All i want is to set the movie like to 1 instead of 0.

I have a Movie DB api which i use to fetch and display movie info to the user.
then i use firebase authentication to log in and then the user clicks the like button and it should save the value 1 to the db.

I am new to React and don't fully understand the concepts, so if its something stupid i'm sorry.

Here is the error:

```
TypeError: this.props.likeMovie is not a function

AddLike.likeMovie

C:////

23 |        this.setState({
24 |            newMovieContent: 1,
25 |        })
> 26 |        this.props.likeMovie(this.state.newMovieContent);
27 |    }
28 | 
29 |    render(){
```

Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class AddLike extends Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        newMovieContent: 0,
    };

    this.handleUserInput = this.handleUserInput.bind(this);
    this.likeMovie = this.likeMovie.bind(this);
}




likeMovie(){
    this.setState({
        newMovieContent: 1,
    })
    this.props.likeMovie(this.state.newMovieContent);
}

render(){
    return(

            <div>
            <button
            onClick={this.likeMovie}>Like</button>
        </div>   
    )
  }
   }

 export default AddLike;
```

Movie row

addMovieRecord is adding like value 1, will have more data later.(that is why called that instead of addlike)

```
class MovieRow extends React.Component {

constructor(props, context) {
super(props, context);

this.addMovieRecord = this.addMovieRecord.bind(this);
this.removeMovie = this.removeMovie.bind(this);

this.app = fire;
this.database = this.app.database().ref().child('movies');

 this.state = {
  show: false,
  movies: [],
  };

   componentWillMount(){
  const previousMovies = this.state.movies;
 //ADD
  this.database.on('child_added', snap => {
  previousMovies.push({
    id: snap.key,
    movieRecord: snap.val().movieRecord,
  })
  this.setState({
    movies: previousMovies
     })
   })
     //REMOVE
      this.database.on('child_removed', snap => {
      for(var i=0; i < previousMovies.length; i++){
      if(previousMovies[i].id === snap.key){
        previousMovies.splice(i, 1);
      }
      }
      this.setState({
        movies: previousMovies
        })
        })
     }

       //ADD
        addMovieRecord(movie){
           this.database.push().set({movieRecord: movie});
      }
          //REMOVE
           removeMovie(movieId){
                this.database.child(movieId).remove();
     }

      render() {
        return <div key={this.props.movie.id}>
      <div className="row">
      <div className="col-md-4 card card-body">
        <img src={this.props.movie.poster_src} style={{width:'15em', height:'20em'}} 
      className="thumbnail" alt="Poster" />
       </div>
      <div className="col-md-8">
        <h2 className="mb-4">{this.props.movie.title}</h2>
        <ul className="list-group">
          <li className="list-group-item">
            <strong>Released:</strong> {this.props.movie.release_date}
          </li>
          <li className="list-group-item">
            <strong>Rated:</strong> {this.props.movie.popularity}
          </li>


          <li className="list-group-item">
          <AddLike addMovieRecord={this.addMovieRecord}/>
          {
        this.state.movies.map((movie) => {
          return (
            <Movie movieRecord={movie.movieRecord} 

            moviId={this.props.movie.id} 
            key={this.props.movie.id} 
            removeNote ={this.removeNote}/>
          )
        })
      }
          </li>

        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
    <>
    <Button variant="primary" onClick={this.handleShow}>
      Show More Information
    </Button>

    <Modal show={this.state.show} onHide={this.handleClose}>
      <Modal.Header closeButton>
        <Modal.Title>{this.props.movie.title}</Modal.Title>
      </Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body>{this.props.movie.overview}</Modal.Body>
      <Modal.Footer>
        <Button variant="secondary" onClick={this.handleClose}>
          Close
        </Button>
      </Modal.Footer>
    </Modal>
     </>

    <hr/>






         </div>
       }
      }

     export default MovieRow
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `<AddLike addMovieRecord={this.addMovieRecord} />` -- you are not providing a value for `likeMovie` and you don't seem to have `defaultProps` set. So within the `AddLike` component, `this.props.likeMovie` is `undefined` and not a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function passed in as a prop to the `AddLike` component is called `addMovieRecord`, so you need to call `this.props.addMovieRecord` instead of `this.props.likeMovie`.

`setState` is also asynchronous, so using `this.state.newMovieContent` directly after updating it will not give you the latest value. You can call `addMovieRecord` in a callback given to `setState` instead:

```
likeMovie(){
    this.setState({
        newMovieContent: 1,
    }, () => {
        this.props.addMovieRecord(this.state.newMovieContent);
    });
}
```